# Can't Install .NET 4.6

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am getting a strange error while trying to install .NET 4.6 or .NET 4.5.2 and I wondering if there is a way of getting around it:

[image]

In Visual Studio I can't see the framework even when I try to open an application in .NET 4.5.2 - I get a message asking me to upgrade:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [.NET 4.6 Targeting Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48136) to target .NET 4.6 in Visual Studio versions earlier than 2015:

> The .NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack is a package that enables developers to build applications targeting the .NET Framework 4.6 using either Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012 or third party IDEs. You need to download and install the .NET Framework 4.6 prior to installing the targeting pack.

where the .NET 4.6 Framework can be downloaded [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=48130) (it's *part* of Windows from Windows 10 onwards so you won't need to install it).

---

Likewise, it looks like you need the [.NET 4.5.2 Targeting Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42637) for a similar reason for Visual Studio versions earlier than 2013.

---

For reference, this table is compiled from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) for Visual Studio:

```
Visual       Latest .NET
Studio       version supported
version      w/o targeting pack

2010 (10.0)  4.0    
2012 (11.0)  4.5    
2012 (11.0)  4.5.1  
2012 (11.0)  4.5.2  
2015 (14.0)  4.6
```